# Zonal Statistics as Table gives error when there is no overlap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I'm trying to generate Zonal Statistics with a raster and set of polygons.

In my case the polygons represent census tracts in the US and the raster is population density.

The problem is that sometimes the raster and polygon don't overlap, because the raster only includes the lower 48 states, and I'm writing a script to loop over files from all states to do this operation, and those files include some Alaska/Hawaii files.

Is there a function to check if a raster and a polygon overlap?

Right now I'm working on ArcMap and just copying as snippet as I go:

[image]

This gives an error, because state number 02 is Alaska. Ideally it would be smart enough to skip this case.

Comment: Perhaps use extent.polygon and intersects for geometry.

Answer (score -1):

You can determine if two layers overlap using the Intersect tool.  Part of the standard toolbox in ArcGIS

Comment: That tool doesn't seem to work for rasters... Only polygons. Plus, it creates a feature, while all I need is a True or False result.

Comment: The raster overlay tool might work but it again delivers a dataset.  You should be able to use ArcPY to get what you want.  What is the specific error that you are getting from zonal statistics?  It's seems like it shouldn't error out but just deliver zero if the layers don't coincide.

Comment: It's not a very useful error: ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (ZonalStatisticsAsTable).

Comment: Are you getting any results?   If not then are you sure both layers are in the same projection?

Comment: no results. They are in the same projection (projected before). The issue is that no part of the polygon overlaps the raster. This is fine doing manually, but I wanted a way to loop over a bunch of polygon files and check for overlap before trying this. Right now I'm just manually hard-coding the states that don't overlap.